# Sitecore 9.1 IdentityServer AzureAD subprovider user cannot login to the Admin site

Tags: federated-authentication, identity-server

I have configured Sitecore Identity to use Azure AD as the sub provider following the [Sitecore document](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html)

I can authenticate using my Azure AD account, but then I get the following message

> You do not have access to the system. If you think this is wrong,
>   please contact the system administrator.

I added the claimtransformation as per the document with no luck
[image: I added the claimtransformation as per the document with no luck]

What am I missing?

Comment: The claims configuration didn't work for me.
I followed the whole tutorial from the link above (https://sitecore.derekc.net/setting-up-azure-active-directory-integration-with-sitecore-identity-server-sitecore-9-1/) Anyone else with the same problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://sitecore.derekc.net/setting-up-azure-active-directory-integration-with-sitecore-identity-server-sitecore-9-1/ might have your solution -- he writes:

> "just 'cuz you're in AD, doesn't mean you're automatically allowed to log in to Sitecore."

You'll need to map group membership in Active Directory to roles in Sitecore.

The link then walks you through this mapping process.