# Login to Sitecore using Azure AD integration

Tags: azure

We are using Sitecore 10.1.1. We have integrated Azure AD with Sitecore so that users can use their Azure accounts to login to Sitecore.

Everything worked fine for all users, and then we got a request from a user to add him to a particular role to Sitecore. We added the user to the Azure AD group but the user is getting error -

*"You do not have access to the system. If you think this is wrong, please contact the system administrator."*

We have verified the Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProvider.AzureAd.xml config. We have correctly mapped the group id to the Sitecore role. Also the tenant and client id looks correct.

We deleted the user from Sitecore, restarted the Identity server and asked user again to login but still same error.

Any inputs?

Comment: this will helps https://sitecoresysadmin.wordpress.com/2020/04/17/troubleshooting-guide-to-you-do-not-have-access-to-the-system-in-sitecore-identity-server/

Comment: check this link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17301/sitecore-9-1-identityserver-azuread-subprovider-user-cannot-login-to-the-admin-s

Answer (score 0):

If it is working for other users, but not for that particular user, then it is most likely due to the number of security groups that the failing user is a member of. During the login process, all information about group membership is added to the response. If the number of groups is to many then the size of the response exceeds the size limit.

The simplest approach is to **reduce the number of groups the user is a member of**, or try and increase the size limit. This can be done by increasing the value of maxRequestLength in web config.

The [article linked to in the comments](https://sitecoresysadmin.wordpress.com/2020/04/17/troubleshooting-guide-to-you-do-not-have-access-to-the-system-in-sitecore-identity-server/) goes into alot more details about the issue. Other recommended work arounds are:

- Move your Identity Provider from the App Service to a Windows Server VM where you have access to those registry keys
- increase the value of MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` registry
- Create a separate Azure Active Directory for managing just Sitecore groups
- Move the Sitecore permissions from the “Azure AD Security Groups” to “Azure AD Application Roles”

Comment: Well, done some more investigation. This is happening if I add user to just one particular group in azure. If I assign that role to user directly in sitecore then it works, so sitecore role seems to be correct. Some thing wrong with azure ad grp. I cross verified the object it in my Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProvider.AzureAd.xml, seems to be correct

Comment: Is it possible that the azure group has other groups nested within?

Comment: No, Checked that as well. Even I tried creating a new group in azure and mapped it in Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProvider.AzureAd.xml with a new sitecore role but same issue there as well.

Comment: Did you try the PS from that article? If so how many groups did it show?
$FindUser = “username@domain.com”
(Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $FindUser | Get-AzureADUserMembership -All $true | ? {$_.ObjectType -ne “Role”} | % {Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $_.ObjectId | select DisplayName,ObjectType,MailEnabled,SecurityEnabled,ObjectId} | ? {$_.SecurityEnabled -eq $true}).count

Comment: I didn't try the PS script. But I checked the [Sitecore_Core].[dbo].[ExternalUserData] table in core database. I saw the data field for my user for which I was getting issue. So many groups are coming as part of the response(including the one which I added for that user).

Comment: The reason for running the script is to see the total number of groups being sent back from azure. If it is too high, then that is the problem you are facing.

Comment: I tired running the script as well. My user is part of only 16 groups. Out of which only one is sitecore. Not sure what else could be the issue.